# Java: convert binary string to hex string

Tags: java, binary, hex

I need to convert the binary string to a hex string but i have a problem.
I  converted the binary string to a hex string by this method:

```
public static String binaryToHex(String bin){
   return Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(bin,2));
}
```

it's ok! but I lose the zeros to the left of the string.
Ex:

the method return this: 123456789ABCDEF,
but i want returned this:

00000123456789ABCDEF

Comment: can't you just append the missing 0's by hand?

Comment: Use `String.format` method to append the `String` with `0's`

Comment: The reason why you loose them is because leading zero's in a Long have no value.
You'll either have to change the way you process your conversion, or you will have to add them again by yourself. The String.format that @RohitJain suggested has my preference as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `Long.toHexString` I would use `Long.parseLong` to parse the value and then `String.format` to output the value with the desired width (21 in your example):

```
public static String binaryToHex(String bin) {
   return String.format("%21X", Long.parseLong(bin,2)) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but works

```
public static String binaryToHex(String bin) {
    String hex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(bin, 2));
    return String.format("%" + (int)(Math.ceil(bin.length() / 4.0)) + "s", hex).replace(' ', '0');
}
```

I've used String.format() to left pad string with whitespaces then called replace() to replace it with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the zeros manually. Here's one way:

```
public static String binaryToHex(String bin){
    return ("0000000000000000" + Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(bin, 2)).replaceAll(".*.{16}", "$1");
}
```