# How to get Wi-Fi Mac address in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android

I am using WiFi MAC address as Unique id, from Marshmallow onwards returning **fake MAC address**(for security reason).   With this my Android application behaves differently.  How to get the actual MAC address of the Android device.

I am using the following code-snippet.

```
WifiManager wmgr = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String wifiId = wmgr.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

Following permissions are added in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Is the app connected with wifi?

Comment: Marshmallow has disabled the MAC address access though you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329733/how-to-get-the-missing-wifi-mac-address-on-android-m-preview  may be helpful to try alternate way to get MAC address from network cat file  and refer here for details of new permission changes for bluetooth and wifi MAC http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/android-6-0-marshmallow-thoroughly-reviewed/5/

Comment: cat /sys/class/net/[IFACE]/address - where [IFACE] can be wlan0, wlan1, etc... However, it may need to be noted that on some devices this is read-protected, so you may need root.

Comment: Hi @Android WeblineIndia, App connected to WiFi. it is returning fake address  02:00:00:00:00:00. I tried the given link;  getHardwareAddress from interface is not working & it is difficulty to get actual MAC address it is based on the 'interfaceName' (interface name are not constant across the devices).  Any other options not-rooted device?

Comment: Please check this solution, it works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329733/how-to-get-the-missing-wifi-mac-address-on-android-m-preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MAC address in Android 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159224/getting-mac-address-in-android-6-0)

Comment: duplicate question , however this is the complete right answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41142980/3818437

Comment: I posted here working solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789324/5330408

Answer (score 60):

There is a work-around to get the Mac address in Android 6.0.

First you need to add Internet user permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then you can find the mac over the NetworkInterfaces API.

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Source: http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically

Comment: Perhaps easier to convert to hex like so? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493873/java-convert-binary-string-to-hex-string

Comment: does this work in all versions of android or only in version 6? thanks

Comment: Also, any idea if it still requires wifi to be turned on on some devices in order to get the value?  Thanks.

Comment: @BooberBunz I've checked it on android 5.0, it works. And it also works with wifi turned off.

Comment: Also converting bytes to hex works incorrectly. I have :05 in my mac address and it gives me :5. So, I use String.format("%02x", b) to convert.

Comment: I've seen interfaces being named differently on Linux depending on the driver being used for example; my WiFi adapter is **ensp0**. I don't know if this is the case with Android

Comment: I would also change the `return "";` to `continue` to allow to check for any further `NetworkInterface`s

Comment: does anyone know a solution for appcelerator?

Comment: @raypixar You didn't have `wlan0`. Does that mean that it is not necessary for an Android device to have an interface with that name?

Comment: but it always return static mac for all devices 02:00:00 and so on .

Comment: The above solution is working in 6.0, but after update of 7.0 this function will return "02:00:00:00:00:00".

Comment: @beginner Strange, It works on my Android 7.0 device

Comment: @cesargastonec Based on the later updates in 7.0, this function is working promptly.                                           The MAC address information is restricted to Device Owner, Profile Owner, and Carrier apps (which will only obtain addresses for configurations which they create). Other callers will receive a default "02:00:00:00:00:00" MAC address.

Answer (score -2):

I went to my Netgear router interface and looked for the tab listing connected devices which nicely produced the MAC ID.

If in doubt, turn off the device and view the list, then turn it on and view again. The new listing is your MAC ID. Edit the router listing to show that.

A bigger view, how could they really hide you MAC ID since it's one of primary identifiers for the world wide surveillance state?