# Getting Mac Address Android 6.0 with appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator

I know there is questions regarding mac address on 6.0, i get the same result of 02:00:00:00. From looking at other answers it does look possible, my problem is i am using appcelerator and this no longer works `Ti.Platform.macaddress`. i have seen this alternative [How to get Wi-Fi Mac address in Android Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103798/how-to-get-wi-fi-mac-address-in-android-marshmallow)  however can't implement it in appcelerator.

Any help would be much appreciated.